# Is it possible to combine these two queries wtih a join in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to create a JOIN in SQLite between these two queries from different tables...

```
SELECT EventId as event, 
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'computer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as computer,
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'desk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as desk,
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'chair' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as chair 
FROM TagsMSCV 
WHERE name IN ('computer','desk','chair') 
GROUP BY EventId
```

...and something like...

```
SELECT COUNT(MicrosoftId) as total FROM Images WHERE Images.EventId = TagsMSCV.EventId
```

...So that the top query goes from producing...

```
event   computer   desk   chair   
####    ########   ####   #####
etc...
```

to

```
event   computer   desk   chair   total
####    ########   ####   #####   #####
etc...
```

EDIT: The second query I wrote was pseudo code attempting to create the join. The actual query as a normal select looks like this...

```
SELECT Count(MicrosoftId) FROM Images WHERE EventId IN ("10003", "10004", etc.) GROUP BY EventId
```

Comment: when you use join you need a column that its values shared between to querys, what is that column in second query?

Comment: The column is called 'EventId' which is the same in the 'Images' table and the 'TagsMSCV' table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the aggregation first and then `left join`:

```
SELECT t.EventId as event, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'computer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as computer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'desk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as desk,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'chair' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as chair,
       i.total
FROM TagsMSCV t LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.eventId, COUNT(MicrosoftId) as total
      FROM Images i
      GROUP BY i.eventId
     ) i
     ON i.EventId = t.EventId 
WHERE t.name IN ('computer', 'desk', 'chair') 
GROUP BY t.EventId, i.total;
```

By doing the aggregation first, you prevent double counting.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Amazing, thank you.